# How to flip vertically UIViewController which is presented modally

Tags: iphone

How can I vertically flip a `UIViewController` which is presented modally along with a `UINavigationController` and Done Button.

This is how I am presenting the `UIViewController` modally:

```
- (void)modalViewAction:(id)sender
{
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] autorelease];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    _viewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
    UIBarButtonItem * button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];
    [_viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:button animated:YES];
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [navigationController release];
}
```

How can I flip this `UIViewController` whilst presenting it modally?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the desired animation technique by setting the `modalTransitionStyle` property (before presenting the view controller).

Unfortunately this property can be set only to:

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl
```

So vertical flip it is not supported.

Take a look at UIModalTransitionStyle reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html